# Display wont work in ASUS M7600QC

Tags: laptop, display, asus-laptop

Today my display just went out unexpectedly. But laptop seems to work. I can hear the cooler. Also led indicators works, power indicator lights white color and battery charge indicator slowly blinks white color. Cannot find anywhere what this could mean. I tried connect second display, this also does not work. Found some guides about BIOS reset and they do not resolve the problem too. By the way, FN + F7 and other combinations, doesn't work at all the same way

Comment: Since you, "tried connect second display, this also does not work," presumably through HDMI or other video port, this seems likely a *hardware* issue. When you try to enter BIOS, does the display work? If not, then likely a chip is bad, unless a cable came loose.

Comment: nope. display do not work at all. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, since an external display does not work (precluding a simple dead LCD light), and it won't show anything in BIOS, you have a few choices:

- Attempt to [use the PC "headless"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_computer), i.e., without display (or using a *remotely connected display*), **if** it can be booted and controlled remotely, e.g., through [Remote Desktop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-remote-desktop-5fe128d5-8fb1-7a23-3b8a-41e636865e8c), [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/), or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/remote-desktop-connection/). Setting up remote control while operating blind is nontrivial, but possible.
- Have it repaired. Get a quote on the cost -- it might be less expensive to buy a new PC.
- Donate it to a school for parts or for their attempt at repair.
- If you're an electronic "hacker" (in the older sense of the word), take it apart yourself. Use your old HDD or SSD in an external USB adapter, and access existing data. *Be careful with a lithium battery, which can catch fire.*